# Diffrent width and height images layout question in Laravel with fancybox

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, fancybox

Here is Photo viewer laravel project. it worked well. but I'm having problem about image layout.
This below image is my current photo gallery page. As you can see images are not line. looks not good.

[image]

Becase each uploaded photo size are diffrent width and height so this happens I guess.
I'm using Laravel. And this is fancybox. 
and I'm using this gentleman's source code. 
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-image-gallery-crud-example-from-scratchexample.html

I had been changing below css parameter but I couldn't fix.
Could you teach me code to fix situation please?

**CSS of index.blade.php**

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- References: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
   .gallery
    {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 20px;      

    }   

    .form-image-upload{
        background: #e8e8e8 none repeat scroll 0 0;
        padding: 15px;

    }
```

**Image output of Index.blade.php**

```
<div class='list-group gallery'>
            @if($images->count())
                @foreach($images as $image)
                <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="images/{{ $image->image }}">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/{{ $image->image }}" />
                        <div class='text-center'>
                            <small class='text-muted'>No.{{ $image->id }}</small>
                        </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
                    </a>                

                </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
```

Comment: You have to use image width and height

Comment: Simply google for "css image grid", there are plenty of resources, for example, https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: Dear @janis Thank you for answering me. Wow! that sounds very interesting. I'm sorry not this time but I will use this future. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use Image Width and Height just like this

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/{{ $image->image }}" height="48" width="48"/> // Here 48 in pixel size
```

Comment: Dear @A.A Noman Thank you for answering me. Sorry I didn't get usage.but now I got it. well... I tried your code. and it became better but  still some  images are look not line. some images are vertical some of are horizon.

Comment: If you do align your image then when a user upload an image then check the validation or resize your image as you expect. Then all images are looking good as you expect @greeniron

Comment: Dear @A.A Noman. Yes. You are totally right. but I have to accept any images shape. as you can see my current image. something pushing another images. Do you have another way to align this?

Comment: You have no problem. You can accept all shape of images. But when you save the image  first resize it then save it. Hope it solves your problem. Or you have to maintain strictly `image-responsive`@greeniron

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I will do your way. I really apreciate.

Comment: You are most welcome @greeniron. I am very happy because my little contribution help your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can add a break line every 4 pictures to make it look cleaner - assuming you are using Bootstrap 4:

```
    @foreach($images as $image)
    <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="images/{{ $image->image }}">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/{{ $image->image }}" />
            <div class='text-center'>
                <small class='text-muted'>No.{{ $image->id }}</small>
            </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
        </a>                

    </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->

    @if ($image->number % 4 == 0)
        <div class="w-100"></div>
    @endif

    @endforeach
```

Comment: Hi. Dear @Christophe Hubert. You answering me again. Thank you. I tried your code but looks same. I update bootstrap link. and my bootstrap version is 3.3.7.